# iCloud wont sync on the first launch

Tags: ios, load, synchronization, icloud

I have a bug where my app wont pull icloud inforamtion on the first launch but it does on the subsequent tries. here is my code to load a file from icloud.

> void DLC::loadFromiCloud(std::string fileName){
>
> > NSURL *mUbiqUrl = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
> >
> > if (mUbiqUrl)
> >        {
> >
> > > ```
> > > std::string fullPath = getLibraryPath_iOS() + fileName;
> > >
> > > NSString* restorePath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(fullPath.c_str())];
> > >     NSError *error = nil;
> > >     NSURL *fileToDownload = [mUbiqUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(fileName.c_str())]];
> > >     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:fileToDownload 
> > >                                                 error:&error];
> > >     if (error != nil)
> > >     {
> > >         NSLog(@"iCloud L2 error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
> > >     }
> > >     else 
> > >     {
> > >         NSNumber*  isIniCloud = nil;
> > >         if ([fileToDownload getResourceValue:&isIniCloud forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey error:nil])
> > >         {
> > >             // If the item is in iCloud, see if it is downloaded.
> > >             if ([isIniCloud boolValue]) 
> > >             {
> > >                 NSNumber*  isDownloaded = nil;
> > >                 if ([fileToDownload getResourceValue:&isDownloaded forKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey error:nil]) 
> > >                 {
> > >                     if ([isDownloaded boolValue])
> > >                     {
> > >                         NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileToDownload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
> > >                         //NSLog(@"iCloud data: %@", fileData);
> > >                         [fileData writeToFile:restorePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
> > >                         if (error)
> > >                         {
> > >                             NSLog(@"iCloud L3 error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
> > >                         }
> > >                     }
> > >                 }
> > >             }
> > >         }
> > >     }
> > > }}
> > > ```

Comment: It seem to stop at if ([isDownloaded boolValue])
it never goes to isdownloaded it seems to endlessly stay in isdownloading